# Erro: No converter found capable of converting from type no Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot

A query no Repository:

```
@Query("""
            SELECT DATE(dataHora) as data, min(temperatura) as minima, max(temperatura) as maxima, SUM(chuva) as chuva
            FROM Historico
            GROUP BY DATE(dataHora)
            """)
    List<HistoricoDiario> listarHistoricoDiario();
```

A classe Record:

```
public record HistoricoDiario(String data, Double minima, Double maxima, Double chuva) {
}
```

A chamada no Controller:

```
public List<HistoricoDiario> historicoPorDia(){
    return historicoRepository.listarHistoricoDiario();

}
```

Ao executar, gera este erro:

No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [br.com.xxxxxx.api.domain.historico.HistoricoDiario]",

Comment: Did you try `SELECT NEW HistoricoDiario(DATE(dataHora), min(temperatura), max(temperatura), SUM(chuva) ...`?